# IMPORTXML() only works on a part of the xPath

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets

I would like to download parts (i.e. specific rows and columns ... cells) from the Balance Sheet information found here:

https://www.barchart.com/stocks/quotes/AAPL/balance-sheet/annual

Using 'xPath' for Chrome I have:

```
/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/ng-transclude/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[3]
```

Using 'xPath Helper' for Chrome I have:

```
/html/body/div[@id='bc-main-content-wrapper']/div[@class='inner-wrap']/div[@class='main-content-wrapper content js-main-content-wrapper ']/div[@class='row']/div[@class='large-12 columns']/div[@class='one-column-block']/div[@class='row']/div[@id='main-content-column']/div[@class='column-inner']/div[@class='bc-financial-report']/div[@class='bc-table-scrollable']/div[@class='bc-table-scrollable-inner']/ng-transclude/table[@class='ng-scope']/tbody/tr[4]/td[3]
```

but I'm only able return all data from the web page with parts of the paths - i.e.:

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]")
```

and:

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"/html/body/div[@id='bc-main-content-wrapper']/div[@class='inner-wrap']/div[@class='main-content-wrapper content js-main-content-wrapper']/div[@class='row']/div[@class='large-12 columns']/div[@class='one-column-block']/div[@class='row']/div[@id='main-content-column']/div[@class='column-inner']/div[@class='bc-financial-report']")
```

Initially I thought it had something to do with 'ng-transclude'-section ... but as you can see, I don't even reach that part of the path.

I hope that someone can point me in the right direction of getting this problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

For whole row: `=index(importhtml("https://www.barchart.com/stocks/quotes/AAPL/balance-sheet/annual","table"),7,)` (example for `Inventories`).

For whole column: `=index(importhtml("https://www.barchart.com/stocks/quotes/AAPL/balance-sheet/annual","table"),,3)` (example for `09-2017`).

For cell: `=index(importhtml("https://www.barchart.com/stocks/quotes/AAPL/balance-sheet/annual","table"),7,3)` (example for `Inventories` for `09-2017`).

Comment: Thank you pnuts for your very elegant and informative solution! On a side note - I managed to access data via a Google script - the following way (not so pretty - but it works): doc.html.body.div[1].div.div[1].div[1].div.div[1].div.div.div.div[2].getElements()[1].table.tbody.tr[index].td[3].getText().replace("$", "").split(",").join("");